# Python codecs module

Tags: python

I am trying to load a file saved as UTF-8 into python (ver2.6.6) which contains 14 different languages. I am using the python `codecs` module to decode the txt file.

```
import codecs
f = open('C:/temp/list_test.txt', 'r')
    for lines in f:
        line=filter_str(lines.decode("utf-8")
```

This all works well. I parse the entire file and then want to export 
14 different language files. The problem that I can't understand is the following

I use the following code for output:

```
malangout = codecs.open("C:/temp/'polish.txt",'w','utf-8','surrogateescape')
    for item in lang_dic['English']:
         temp = lang_dic[lang1][item]
         malangout.write(temp + '\n')
    malangout.close()
```

Example:

- Language: Polish
- Expected output: Dziennik zakłóceń
- Actual output: Dziennik zak‚óceƒ

The string is stored as is:

```
u'Dziennik zak\u201a\xf3ce\u0192'
```

I have tried many encoding from the python docs (7.8 codecs). Any infomation would help at this point.

Comment: You say in a comment: "I save an ascii file as an UTF-8 in notepad": ascii is a subset of utf8, that wouldn't cause a problem. Do you mean "ANSI" instead of "ascii"? What is the result of `import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())` on your system?

Answer (score 1):

> The string is stored as is:
>
> ```
> u'Dziennik zak\u201a\xf3ce\u0192'
> ```

Well, that's a problem since

```
In [25]: print(u'Dziennik zak\u201a\xf3ce\u0192')
Dziennik zak‚óceƒ
```

in contrast to

```
In [26]: print(u'Dziennik zak\u0142\xf3ce\u0144')
Dziennik zakłóceń
```

So it looks like the unicode you are storing is incorrect. Are you sure it is correct in `C:/temp/list_test.txt`? That is, does `list_test.txt` contain

```
In [28]: u'Dziennik zak\u201a\xf3ce\u0192'.encode('utf-8')
Out[28]: 'Dziennik zak\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\xb3ce\xc6\x92'
```

or

```
In [27]: u'Dziennik zak\u0142\xf3ce\u0144'.encode('utf-8')
Out[27]: 'Dziennik zak\xc5\x82\xc3\xb3ce\xc5\x84'
```

?

---

PS. You may want to change

```
temp + '\n'
```

to

```
temp + u'\n'
```

to make it clear you are adding two `unicode` together to form a `unicode`. 
The two lines above have the same result in Python2, but in Python3 adding a `unicode` and `str` together would raise a `TypeError`. Even though in Python3, `'\n'` is `unicode`, I think the challenge in transitioning to Python3 will be in changing one's mental attitude toward mixing `unicode` and `str`. In Python2 it is silently attempted for you, in Python3 it is disallowed.

Comment: you bring up a great point. it is stored that way. I save an ascii file as an UTF-8 in notepad and i don't think you can do that

Comment: do i need to do a special remapping before saving as UTF-8?

Comment: Your Python code looks fine overall (see PS above). There may be an indentation problem in the post, but besides that, I don't see a problem.

Comment: ok so the problem is my data file and the way it is stored correct

Comment: Yes, stay away from notepad. :)

Comment: -1 The remarks on Python 3 are (words fail me). In Python 3, that code's `open()` is in text mode, so `lines` will be a `str` object, so `lines.decode("utf-8")` will fail. Options are to use `codecs.open()` (lines will be a `str` object) or to `open(..., 'rb')` then decode `lines` (a `bytes` object). So you end up with you want: `str` objects which are the utf8-decoded file contents. When you get to output, `temp` will still be a `str` object (assuming it's not mangled by the code we've not been shown). `'\n'` is a `str` object. No type error. In Python 3, `u'\n'` is a syntax error.